# Memory allocation doesn't work when I change the structure related to it

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I'm currently working with a structure

```
struct Player{
   Object obj;
   int touched;
};
typedef struct Player *Player;
```

And here's the creation of an element from this structure :

```
Player createPlayer(int posiX,int posiY){
    Player p;
    p=malloc(sizeof(p));
    p->obj.posi.x=posiX;
    p->obj.posi.y=posiY;
    p->obj.life=100;
    p->touched=0;
    p->obj.damage=5;
    p->obj.friend=true;
    return p;
}
```

Like this every compile perfectly.
But if I had 2 elements in my structure,

```
struct Player{
   Object obj;
   int touched;
   int frequency;
   int lastTouch;
};
typedef struct Player *Player;
```

I got this error message at the execution (The code compile perfectly) :

malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
Aborted (core dumped)

I don't understand why I got this error message, because I don't use yet these two new variables.

Comment: `typedef struct Player *Player;` must be one of the most unnerving type definitions in history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining `Player` as a pointer, you should probably define it as is. Like this:

```
struct Player{
   Object obj;
   int touched;
};
typedef struct Player Player_t;
```

Then do this:

```
Player_t *createPlayer(int posiX,int posiY){
    Player_t *p = malloc(sizeof(Player_t));
    p->obj.posi.x=posiX;
    p->obj.posi.y=posiY;
    p->obj.life=100;
    p->touched=0;
    p->obj.damage=5;
    p->obj.friend=true;
    return p;
}
```

As a side note: It is never a good idea to `typedef` pointers as you can never know if it is a pointer or not from its name or declaration elsewhere. You should at the very least explicitly say that it is a pointer like this:

```
typedef struct Player *PlayerPtr;
```

or

```
typedef struct Player *Player_p;
```

Answer (score 2):

At the line

```c
p=malloc(sizeof(p));
```

you are allocating only for a pointer while allocating for the whole structure is required.

You should do:

```c
p=malloc(sizeof *p);
```

Add `*` to dereference the pointer and get the structure type.

Using `typedef` to obscure pointers like `typedef struct Player *Player;` is not recommended because it can cause this type of confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will modify that immediately !